# Call a stored procedure with another in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Does anyone know of a way, or even if its possible, to call a stored procedure from within another? If so, how would you do it?

Here is my test code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DROP PROCEDURE test_sp_1;
DROP PROCEDURE test_sp;

CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test works');
END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp_1
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Testing');
    test_sp;
END;
/

CALL test_sp_1;
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your stored procedures work as coded. The problem is with the last line, it is unable to invoke either of your stored procedures.

Three choices in SQL*Plus are: `call`, `exec`, and an anoymous PL/SQL block.

`call` appears to be a SQL keyword, and is documented in the SQL Reference. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4008.htm#BABDEHHG The syntax diagram indicates that parentesis are required, even when no arguments are passed to the call routine.

```
CALL test_sp_1();
```

An anonymous PL/SQL block is PL/SQL that is not inside a named procedure, function, trigger, etc. It can be used to call your procedure.

```
BEGIN
    test_sp_1;
END;
/
```

`Exec` is a SQL*Plus command that is a shortcut for the above anonymous block. `EXEC <procedure_name>` will be passed to the DB server as `BEGIN <procedure_name>; END;`

Full example:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp 
  2  AS 
  3  BEGIN 
  4      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test works'); 
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp_1 
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Testing'); 
  5      test_sp; 
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> CALL test_sp_1();
Testing
Test works

Call completed.

SQL> exec test_sp_1
Testing
Test works

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2      test_sp_1;
  3  end;
  4  /
Testing
Test works

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: `CALL` didn't work for me, but calling the procedure like `procedure_name(parameters);` did

Answer (score 20):

Sure, you just call it from within the SP, there's no special syntax.

Ex:

```
   PROCEDURE some_sp
   AS
   BEGIN
      some_other_sp('parm1', 10, 20.42);
   END;
```

If the procedure is in a different schema than the one the executing procedure is in, you need to prefix it with schema name.

```
   PROCEDURE some_sp
   AS
   BEGIN
      other_schema.some_other_sp('parm1', 10, 20.42);
   END;
```

Comment: Thanks for that however when I try to run that using CALL sp_1;
I get the following error. 
Error starting at line 21 in command:
CALL test_sp_1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
06576. 00000 -  "not a valid function or procedure name"
*Cause:    Could not find a function (if an INTO clause was present) or
           a procedure (if the statement did not have an INTO clause) to
           call.
*Action:   Change the statement to invoke a function or procedure

Comment: @Michael Lockwood - Can you post your code in your original question? Also, if you are calling a function using a tool like SQL*PLus, you need to assign the return value to a variable.

Comment: @ML: why are you still trying to use CALL when CALL doesn't work (is not a valid PL/SQL statement) and dcp has shown you how to do it correctly?

Comment: Thanks for this! I was stuck trying to precede the procedure name with `EXEC` or `EXECUTE`, as (I think) would be necessary to invoke the procedure independently -- but was getting an error. I didn't realize that inside another procedure, I could just call the procedure by name, without a preceding command.

Comment: Is it possible to use results from called stored procedure? (select statement)

Comment: @FrenkyB - That's really a completely different question. But in general, you can pass a parameter by reference to the stored procedure if you intend to use its value in the calling procedure/function.  In Oracle, you pass a parameter by reference by specifying that it's an "OUT" parameter.  If you are looking to get the results of a select statement returned to your procedure, then check out ref cursors.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587292/what-is-pass-by-reference-in-oracle/31588096 for examples of passing by reference.

Answer (score 5):

@Michael Lockwood - you don't need to use the keyword "CALL" anywhere. You just need to mention the procedure call directly.

That is

```
Begin
   proc1(input1, input2);
end;
/
```

instead of

```
Begin
   call proc1(input1, input2);
end;
/
```

Comment: Looking at his code, and the revision history to the question, I don't see where he is using call within PL/SQL. The call is outside of any PL/SQL, and an attempt to test the stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

To invoke the procedure from the SQLPlus command line, try one of these:

```
CALL test_sp_1();
EXEC test_sp_1
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling one procedure from another procedure:

One for a normal procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SP_1() AS 
BEGIN
/*  BODY */
END SP_1;
```

Calling procedure SP_1 from SP_2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SP_2() AS
BEGIN
/* CALL PROCEDURE SP_1 */
SP_1();
END SP_2;
```

Call a procedure with REFCURSOR or output cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SP_1
(
oCurSp1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
/*BODY */
END SP_1;
```

Call the procedure SP_1 which will return the REFCURSOR as an output parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SP_2 
(
oCurSp2 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS `enter code here`
BEGIN
/* CALL PROCEDURE SP_1 WITH REF CURSOR AS OUTPUT PARAMETER */
SP_1(oCurSp2);
END SP_2;
```

Comment: Ritght asnwer for oracle.