# Returning result from stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure which does the select statement. I  have created another stored procedure which calls the earlier stored procedure,but enable to get the result. Below are the scripts

Proc1:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE p_procedure3(custid IN number, custname OUT varchar2) IS
BEGIN

SELECT firstname 
INTO custname
FROM customer_s
WHERE customerid = custid;

END p_procedure3;
```

proc2:

```
create or replace
procedure finalexecution
DECLARE
l_name varchar2(20);
BEGIN

p_procedure3(644, l_name);

dbms_output.put_line(l_name);

END;
```

but when is do exex finalexecution;

getting below error

```
Error starting at line 8 in command:
exec finalexecution
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object CIMNEWUSER.FINALEXECUTION is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second procedure to:

```
create or replace
procedure finalexecution as
  l_name varchar2(20):='';
BEGIN
  p_procedure3(644, l_name);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
END;
```

For more details, refer [Call a stored procedure with another in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415232/call-a-stored-procedure-with-another-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

Your `finalexecution` procedure contains error. You should use `IS` or `AS` instead of `DECLARE`. Check [documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/procedure.htm) for more details.

Also in case if any error, you can check `all_errors` view to find out what is causing the error.

Comment: issue is solved. now next thing is i want to retrieve multiple rows i have written that script please find it below,i know somewhere i have to go with loop but unable to do that please guide me below is the script which gives me result for the last id