# Is it possible to create Function/Procedure which take its parameter from another table.column automatically instead of passing it manually?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create Function/Procedure which take its parameter from another table.column automatically instead of passing it manually?

Comment: PL/SQL can query tables, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67891381/230471